# How to play .ogg files in Adobe AIR app?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, ogg

I've been looking for a way to play sound files in **.ogg** format inside an Adobe AIR app. All information that I found while searhing for about an hour leads to this link which no longer works: [http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Alchemy:Libraries](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Alchemy%3aLibraries)

Any suggestions on how to play .ogg files? Or, can you recommend another free (unlike the mp3) format that can be relatively easily encoded and played inside an AIR mobile app?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you want to play mp3? What's not free about it? (it's the only format playable natively at runtime)

Comment: mp3 is not free: http://mp3licensing.com/help/developers.html

Comment: Playing mp3 from within a swf is free since adobe has already paid for that license. Any other mp3 manipulation is not free. For example loading a wav and converting to mp3 (for the sake of example) would not be free. Recording and saving mp3 to disk is not free.

Comment: Yes, in my question I said "**encoded** and played"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two possibilities:

1.[OggLibrary](https://github.com/papachan/LiveRadio/tree/master/src/com/mauft/OggLibrary)

Sample:

```
[Embed(source="/test.ogg",mimeType="application/octet-stream")] 
private static const OGG_TEST:Class

public function test()
{
   var oggTest:OggEmbed = new OggEmbed(new OGG_TEST() as ByteArray);
   oggTest.play(0);
}
```

2.[Ogg Vorbis Encoder + Decoder for Flash](http://labs.byhook.com/2011/02/22/ogg-vorbis-encoder-decoder-for-flash/)

It seems there aren't *ANE* ready to play **.ogg* (at least I wasn't able to find them).

Comment: Thank you! I tested option 2. The code works fine on PC and Android. On iPad2 it either takes several minutes to encode a 2-second sound, or just hangs. Same happens with ShineMP3Encoder. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found anything about **playing a .ogg stream in Adobe AIR** yet - option 1 from the accepted solution above is not working any more, since *OggLibrary* requires *Alchemy* which I simply can't find on the interwebz any more, and the *Ogg Vorbis Encoder + Decoder for Flash* page states that the library doesn't support .ogg streams.

Any ideas?